# How to simulate android tap, very fast

Tags: android, performance, simulate

I've been trying to simulate an android tap on the touch screen, but very fast.
I want the tap to be on a line, so I fix the y value and I increment a x value of 100 with a modulo 1080.

I precise that I don't really care 'exactly' where it hits. I want to sweep a line with a bunch of hits.

I tried the 'input' method, but it's too slow. I also tried the sendevent method with a shell script (running directly from my phone), but again, it's too slow. I need the script to simulate taps at around 40Hz, or something like that.

I read that we could directly write into the /dev/input/event5 and directly send the bytes (apparently sendevent keeps opening and closing /dev/input/event5, which is slow).

Do you think it's possible, and if yes, how? Can I reach this speed (~40Hz) with a script, or should I try to build a C program instead?

Thank you.

**Edit**: I already have the sequence working to simulate a tap:

```
sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 330 1
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 53 $current_x
sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 54 $y
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 330 0
sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
```

But I'm not sure how to convert that to hexadecimal to directly send it to /dev/input/event5.

**Edit2**: I tried something like that with printf

```
#sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 330 1
printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "1" "330" "1" >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 53 $current_x
printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "3" "53" "$current_x" >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 54 $y
printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "3" "54" "1700" >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 
printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "0" "0" "0" >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 330 0
printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "1" "330" "0" >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "0" "0" "0" >> /dev/input/event5
```

But I feel like printf returns a string, not a hexadecimal value.

**Edit3**: I tried with some bit shift:

```
#sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 330 1
#printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "1" "330" "1" >> /dev/input/event5
echo $(((1<<16) + 330)) >> /dev/input/event5
echo $((1)) >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 53 $current_x
#printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "3" "53" "$current_x" >> /dev/input/event5
echo $(((3<<16) + 53)) >> /dev/input/event5
echo $current_x >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 3 54 $y
#printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "3" "54" "1700" >> /dev/input/event5
echo $(((3<<16) + 54)) >> /dev/input/event5
echo $((1700)) >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 
#printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "0" "0" "0" >> /dev/input/event5
echo $((0)) >> /dev/input/event5
echo $((0)) >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 1 330 0
#printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "1" "330" "0" >> /dev/input/event5
echo $(((1<<16) + 330)) >> /dev/input/event5
echo $((0)) >> /dev/input/event5

#sendevent /dev/input/event5 0 0 0
#printf "%04x%04x%08x\n" "0" "0" "0" >> /dev/input/event5
echo $((0)) >> /dev/input/event5
echo $((0)) >> /dev/input/event5
```

But still nothing. I don't think I'm supposed to send a 64-bits value, because I get this:

```
echo $((1<<32))
1
```

**Edit4**: Hummm, maybe the problem is that I don't have permissions to directly write on */dev/input/event5*, because I tried to monitor it, and I can see things being written when using sendevent, but nothing when piping the echo.

Comment: Have you tried out the Android [UI/Application Exerciser Monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey)?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how Exerciser Monkey could help me for what I'm trying to do. Could you precise please ?